# When is the SoapHeader field instantiated in ASMX?

Tags: asp.net, soap, asmx

Consider the following:

```
public MyCustomHeader MyHeader;

public New()
{
    //MyHeader is NOT instantiated
}


[SoapHeader("MyHeader")]
[WebMethod()]
public bool MyFunction()
{
    //MyHeader is instantiated, but when was it instantiated?
}
```

Comment: Hi, still having a problem with this, or did Mitch answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of your example, it would be instantiated just prior to the execution of the `MyFunction` method.  As the Header was needed to be able to perform the actions of MyFunction.

Comment: What are the other possibilities?  If I added the SoapHeader attribute to the constructor, would it be instantiated there?

Comment: Potentially, the key is that the soap header, is something that comes in with the message, so it isn't instantiated with values until a method call is actually made.

Answer (score 0):

```
how to convert this part and attach to XML in android?
POST /SharingpointCheckBarcode.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: awc.test.trin-it.nl
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/checkBarcode"
```

Comment: Should probably be posted as a separate question to get the best response.

Comment: i was new to stackoverflow didn't know how to post my question so i posted here, now i got knw and posted my question in separate post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814962/sending-xml-to-a-web-service-in-android